# How to debug what happens between php return and the ajax success function being called?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

This is so strange I have a javascript function which has an ajax call back to the server.
On one monitor I have my chrome browser in Inspect mode and watching the messages in the console.
On another monitor I have a terminal window open on my php web server and I am viewing the log messages being output.

The javascript method being called is:

```
  function loadFilters() {
        console.log('loading Filters...');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/filters/load',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('loading Filters...returned successful');
            },
        error: function(response){
                console.log('loading Filters...returned ERROR');
                handleError(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

The route ends up calling the following php method:

```
public function loadFilter(Photos $photos)
{
    $ipAddress = $this->getClientIPAddress();
    Log::info('****** ['.$ipAddress.'] Building View: '.Carbon::now()->format('h:i:s.u'));

    $view = view('console.photos.filter');

    Log::info('****** ['.$ipAddress.'] Returning: '.Carbon::now()->format('h:i:s.u'));
    return $view;
}
```

When I click a button in the browser it calls the javascript method loadFilters().
I see in the console the message 'loading filters...'
Then on the server i see the messages "Building View..." and "Returning" within about 1 second.
As you can see there is nothing after the Returning message except for "return $view;"
But it takes like 30 seconds before the javascript displays 'loading Filters...returned successful'.
There is not much html being returned at that point.
What could possibly cause it to take so long between the return on the server and the success call in javascript?

Comment: is the server on localhost?

Comment: maybe view `console.photos.filter` is heavy, hard to be rendered. maybe exception happens inside view `console.photos.filter`. check the view itself, maybe.

Comment: Looks like the view renders properly and fast judging by the laravel log messages. He could try to add `dataType: 'html'` into the `$.ajax({..., dataType: 'html', ...})` to help the jquery figure out __The type of data that you're expecting back from the server__ [jQuery.ajax() docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).